# Limiting results for api queries

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

#### The Controller

I'm building a ASP.NET API and I have the following controller:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Getstudents()
    {
        IQueryable<student> students = db.students.Include(r => r.instructor);
        return Ok(students);
    }
```

#### The Models

Here's the simplified model for instructor

```
...
public instructor()
{
    students = new HashSet<student>();
}

public int id { get; set; }
...
public ICollection<student> students { get; set; }
...
```

Here's the simplified model for student

```
public student()
{
    ...
}

public int id { get; set; }
public int instructor_id { get; set; }
public instructor instructor { get; set; }
...
```

#### The Results

Everything looks right, except...

```
student_id: 5,
    instructor: {
        id: 3,
        students: [ ]
    },
student_id: 6,
    instructor: {
        id: 4,
        students: {
            id: 5,
        }
    }
student_id: 7,
    instructor: {
        id: 4,
        students: {
            id: 5,
        },
        {
            id: 6
        }
    }
```

See how `instructor` is progressively including all previous students? At first `students` is `[]` then it has student 5, then student 5 and 6. It goes on like that forever.

What am I doing wrong?

If any additional files or information will help, I'll be happy to add it.

Comment: I suspect it's your use of the Include method. What is your intended output?

Comment: To have no students listed under instructors

Comment: How did you generate the results you show here?

Comment: @DavidG by starting the application and calling the API route.

Comment: @crowhill You have to enable LazyLoading on your DbContext... I would guess...

Comment: I would assume the error is caused by relationship fixup and some faulty values being pulled. Are there instructor entries in the database? what do the FK/PK numbers respectively look like? is the foreign key constraint defined in the database?